# Approximate solution to inequality

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, approximation-theory

Working through a problem, I found an inequality that I can't seem to find a closed form solution for. The inequality is as follows:

$$\alpha (1+r+cx)^{-4x} \leq \beta,$$

for which I'm trying to find a closed form solution to $x$. We can simplify this a little by taking logs on both sides,

$$\ln\alpha - 4x\ln(1+r+cx) \leq \ln\beta$$
$$\iff x\ln(1+r+cx) \geq \frac{\ln \alpha - \ln \beta}{4}$$

But I don't think I can simplify this much further.

Now, since I know the value of all parameters except $x$, I can try write some code to figure out close-enough numerical solutions. However, I suspect there must be some prior art on figuring out a closed-form approximation to expressions like these—can anyone point me towards the right ideas?

You may assume that $c>0, r>0, \alpha>0, \beta>0$.

Comment: There is probably a solution using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function): essentially it seems to be of the form $d+x \le k^x$ at least when $x>0$.  Good approximations may depend on the values of $\alpha,\beta,r,c$

Comment: @Henry. I am not sure that Lambert function would work, but ... I may be wrong. Cheers :-)

Comment: Is $\alpha \beta >0$ ? Is $c>0$ ? Is $r>0$ ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I assume that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are greater than $0$ because he applied logs

Comment: @Tortar. Who knows ? In fact, I suppose and hope that $\alpha \beta >0$. My concern is the sign of $c$ and $r$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, $\alpha\beta>0$ and $r>0$

Comment: What about $c$ and $r$ ?

Comment: $c>0$ also. I've clarified this in the question. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the *equation*
$$ x\log(1+r+cx) = \frac 14 \log \left(\frac{\alpha }{\beta }\right)$$ Now, let $$y=cx\qquad \qquad s=r+1 \qquad\qquad k=\frac c4 \log \left(\frac{\alpha }{\beta }\right)$$ and so, we look for the zero of function$$f(y)=y \log(s+y)-k$$ which as a formal solution in terms of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$ in the linked paper).

This being said, from pratical point of view, it is not very useful. For sure the solution is upper bounded by
$$y_{\text{max}}=\frac{k}{W(k)}=a$$

Using a series expansion of $f(y)$ around $y=a$ and series revesion would give
$$y=a+t-\frac{ (a+2 s)}{2 ((a+s) ((a+s) \log (a+s)+a))}t^2+O\left(t^3\right)$$ where
$$t=\frac{k-a \log (a+s)}{\frac{a}{a+s}+\log (a+s)}$$

Trying with $s=12.345$ and $k=2.3456$, this would give, as an *approximation* $y=0.914937$ while the solution, given using Newton method, is $y=0.907670$ (relative error $= 0.80$%).

Adding one more to term to the expansion would lead to the estimate $y=0.908780$ (relative error $= 0.12$%).

$$\color{red} {\text{This needs to be seriously tested on a lot of cases}}$$